# How to save changes in info.plist in react-native project

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I use react-native '0.62.2' and i have some changes that i need to save in 'info.plist'.

**My problem is when i do pod install all the changes are discard.**

I would like to know if there some solution for this situation.

I know that with 'node_modules' this [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) package can help so i wonder if there is some thing for info.plist too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So you are probably changing an info.plist file of one of your pods (i.e. inside your pod folder) instead of the one for your project.

Go to the ios folder, your project folder, and there is the info.plist for your project.

It may be easier to edit if you open xcode and edit it there.

[image]

Comment: @barak109 I added a picture for clarity, make sure you don't misspell the `key` or it will be removed also.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help that what i did in first place

Comment: What is the key you are trying to add? I think it's more likely an issue with how you're adding it. Doing pod install should never override your projects info.plist.

Comment: Yes, i found now the problem, i used node_modules and in the package they change the info.plist so it's solved :)
But thank you it good to know that pod install never override project info.plist